# Accessing Vimeo API from third party websites

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am from I-Maze LLC, we need video editor API for our website so that users can upload and edit the video editor with text/music they want. After editing the video they should be able to save it and they should have option to edit it later if needed, They also should have the access to see their content with specific link. We want to use Vimeo API to do all those works,

Can you please suggest us which API from Vimeo can help us to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to start with the [Getting Started Guide](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start) on the developer site, and the basic [Uploading Videos guide](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/videos/upload). The more advanced [Upload Guide](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos) will probably be necessary for some of the editing.